# Using Postgres for Ruby on Rails and cannot use link deployed by Heroku (Mavericks)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, sqlite, postgresql, heroku

This is my 3rd time around trying to install Ruby on Rails from scratch. This is the same problem I have encountered each time using 3 different tutorials. After everything is finished and I `$ git push heroku master` it gives me a link that doesn't show my web app from git.

```
###### WARNING:
   Include 'rails_12factor' gem to enable all platform features
   See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-integration-gems for more information.

###### WARNING:
   You have not declared a Ruby version in your Gemfile.
   To set your Ruby version add this line to your Gemfile:
   ruby '2.0.0'
   # See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions for more information.

###### WARNING:
   No Procfile detected, using the default web server (webrick)
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server

-----> Discovering process types
   Procfile declares types -> (none)
   Default types for Ruby  -> console, rake, web, worker

-----> Compressing... done, 21.2MB
-----> Launching... done, v6
   http://immense-dusk-3361.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku

To git@heroku.com:immense-dusk-3361.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
MacBook-Air:omrails demo$ heroku open
Opening immense-dusk-3361... done'
```

When I use that link it does not bring me to what I would normally see at Localhost:3000. I followed tutorials to change from **sqlite** to **postgres**. Here is what I ended up with:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: postresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  adapter: postresql
  database: my_database_development
  pool: 5
  host: localhost

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3'
```

The following links are some of the resources I have used:

http://postgresapp.com/documentation/configuration-ruby.html

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#local-setup

Note: I am using One Month Rails tutorial to learn the actual coding but since I am using iOS Mavericks I can't install the kit used from RailsInstaller. I am instead using the: Install Ruby on Rails · Mac OS X Mavericks
by Daniel Kehoe tutorial.

Thanks in advance for helping this pathetic noob! Never stop being awesome :)!

Comment: "When I use that link it does not bring me to what I would normally see" - what do you see on your local environment that you don't on heroku?  I checked the url "http://immense-dusk-3361.herokuapp.com/" and it gives a 404 error, is that your problem?

Comment: I would think that it should show the "Welcome aboard You’re riding Ruby on Rails!" page - The link that Heroku gives me shows "The page you were looking for doesn't exist. You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved."

Comment: from your command prompt, run `heroku run rake db:migrate`.  Also, in your config/environments/production.rb, set config.consider_all_requests_local = true and commit your changes.  This will give you a stacktrace and let you know what's wrong.  You can also run `heroku logs` from your command prompt and show the logs here.